# Iterating through collections to add items but throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, concurrentmodification

```java
package com.ripal;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Outputs {

    public void show() {
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("banana");
        list.add("apple");

        Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();

        Collections.sort(list);
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next() + " ");
        }
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outputs outputs = new Outputs();
        outputs.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ArrayList` has a fail fast iterator. You can modify the collection only via the iterator. Any other modification done outside is detected sooner after calling the iterator methods and a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown. In your case after creating the iterator you sort the array in place and that sorting routine modifies the contents of the array, leading to `ConcurrentModificationException` upon using the iterator. To fix the issue, just perform the sorting before you create the iterator. Here's how it looks.

```
Collections.sort(list);
Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
```

Comment: The alternative is not to deal with iterators when not necessary: `for(String s: list) System.out.println(s);` (The empty space at the end of a line is pointless anyway, the alternative would be `System.out.println(String.join(" ", list));` if that was the actual intention).

Comment: What's interesting about this is that ArrayList's documentation says that a CME is thrown if you _structurally_ modify the list; but sorting an ArrayList isn't a structural modification (it's just moving the elements around in the array) (for example, you can sort a list which can't be structurally modified, `Arrays.asList`). But the source code [explicitly updates the modCount](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L1752).

Comment: Looks like [`replaceAll`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L1732) similarly updates the modCount without structural modification.